# Latexdiff not compiling

Tags: input-encodings, compilation-error, latexdiff, logging

I just found out about Latexdiff and it's just what I need right now. But unfortunatly I can't get the `.tex`-file created by Latexdiff to compile on my maschine. I tried a minimal example:

file nr. 1: ori.tex

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

Hello World

\end{document}
```

file nr. 2: ori_v2.tex

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
    
    Hello to this world!
    
\end{document}
```

They both compile fine.

Running Latexdiff ,however, yields the follwing file, which won't compile:

```
\documentclass{article}

%DIF LATEXDIFF DIFFERENCE FILE
%DIF DEL ori.tex      Wed May 17 14:28:16 2023
%DIF ADD ori_v2.tex   Wed May 17 14:29:17 2023
%DIF PREAMBLE EXTENSION ADDED BY LATEXDIFF
%DIF UNDERLINE PREAMBLE %DIF PREAMBLE
\RequirePackage[normalem]{ulem} %DIF PREAMBLE
\RequirePackage{color}\definecolor{RED}{rgb}{1,0,0}\definecolor{BLUE}{rgb}{0,0,1} %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFadd}[1]{{\protect\color{blue}\uwave{#1}}} %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFdel}[1]{{\protect\color{red}\sout{#1}}}                      %DIF PREAMBLE
%DIF SAFE PREAMBLE %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFaddbegin}{} %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFaddend}{} %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFdelbegin}{} %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFdelend}{} %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFmodbegin}{} %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFmodend}{} %DIF PREAMBLE
%DIF FLOATSAFE PREAMBLE %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFaddFL}[1]{\DIFadd{#1}} %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFdelFL}[1]{\DIFdel{#1}} %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFaddbeginFL}{} %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFaddendFL}{} %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFdelbeginFL}{} %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFdelendFL}{} %DIF PREAMBLE
%DIF COLORLISTINGS PREAMBLE %DIF PREAMBLE
\RequirePackage{listings} %DIF PREAMBLE
\RequirePackage{color} %DIF PREAMBLE
\lstdefinelanguage{DIFcode}{ %DIF PREAMBLE
%DIF DIFCODE_UNDERLINE %DIF PREAMBLE
  moredelim=[il][\color{red}\sout]{\%DIF\ <\ }, %DIF PREAMBLE
  moredelim=[il][\color{blue}\uwave]{\%DIF\ >\ } %DIF PREAMBLE
} %DIF PREAMBLE
\lstdefinestyle{DIFverbatimstyle}{ %DIF PREAMBLE
    language=DIFcode, %DIF PREAMBLE
    basicstyle=\ttfamily, %DIF PREAMBLE
    columns=fullflexible, %DIF PREAMBLE
    keepspaces=true %DIF PREAMBLE
} %DIF PREAMBLE
\lstnewenvironment{DIFverbatim}{\lstset{style=DIFverbatimstyle}}{} %DIF PREAMBLE
\lstnewenvironment{DIFverbatim*}{\lstset{style=DIFverbatimstyle,showspaces=true}}{} %DIF PREAMBLE
%DIF END PREAMBLE EXTENSION ADDED BY LATEXDIFF

\begin{document}

    Hello \DIFdelbegin \DIFdel{World}\DIFdelend \DIFaddbegin \DIFadd{to this world!}\DIFaddend 

\end{document}
```

Trying to compile it, I get the following `.log`-file:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.25 (MiKTeX 23.5) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2023.5.14)  18 MAY 2023 12:57
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**./ori_Diff.tex
(ori_Diff.tex
LaTeX2e <2022-11-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2023-04-20>
! Undefined control sequence.
l.1 \^^@
        d^^@o^^@c^^@u^^@m^^@e^^@n^^@t^^@c^^@l^^@a^^@s^^@s^^@{^^@a^^@r^^@t^^@...
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.


! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.1 \^^@d
         ^^@o^^@c^^@u^^@m^^@e^^@n^^@t^^@c^^@l^^@a^^@s^^@s^^@{^^@a^^@r^^@t^^@...

You're in trouble here.  Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.

Missing character: There is no d in font nullfont!
! Text line contains an invalid character.
l.1 \^^@d^^@
            o^^@c^^@u^^@m^^@e^^@n^^@t^^@c^^@l^^@a^^@s^^@s^^@{^^@a^^@r^^@t^^@...
A funny symbol that I can't read has just been input.
Continue, and I'll forget that it ever happened.
[...]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somehow you have saved the tex diff file in utf-16.

`^^@` is ascii 0 and is appearing because for ascii `\documentclass` saved as utf-16 every other byte is 0.

By uploading the diff code to this site you converted it to utf-8 (the whole site is  utf-8) so your posted code works and gives

[image]

Comment: Okay. Now, dummp question, how do I fix that? I use TeXStudio. My default Setting says utf-8. I tried adding `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` to the `ori_Diff.tex`-file but that did not help. Is this a settings issue with latexdiff?

Comment: Your right, coping the text from the website back into a new file it works. I suppose I could wirte a python program to change the encoding, but that seems like a lot of effort for a work around...

Comment: Using Notepad++ I can resave the file in utf-8 encoding. This fixes it fast. Thank you very much for the fast and quality answer!

Comment: @Jelt0 I do not use latexdiff much but I have never seen it give utf-16. So I can not help with that, you must have a setting somewhere. Glad you can fix in the editor, but obviously getting latexdiff not to use utf-16 would be better